# Examples of homotopy

Tags: general-topology

[image]

I Understand the definition of homopoty and understand somewhat how to apply it. However, i find it difficult to give examples

Comment: Idea: Think of $X =Y$, while $x, y$ are points so that deleting $x$ will "deete" the topology, while deleting $y$ will not.

Answer (score 2):

Try $X = [0, 1]$ with $x = 0$ and $Y = [-1, 1]$ and $y = 0$. It's clear that $X \setminus \{x\} = (0, 1]$ and $Y \setminus \{y\} = [-1, 0) \cup (0, 1]$ and the two can't be homotopy equivalent since $X\setminus\{x\}$ is connected and $Y\setminus\{y\}$.

Another example is to an open disk in $\mathbb{R}^2$ minus a point and the circle $S^1$. Removing a point from the disk results in a space homotopy equivalent to the circle while the circle minus the point is contractible.

Comment: for the first example, i see that $X$ is connected, and $Y$ is not connected, is this enough to conclude that $X\setminus\{x\}$ and $Y\setminus\{y\}$ are not homopoty to each other